# Hook Linux Keyboard Events

Tags: linux, go

This past week at my work we aquired a laser barcode scanner, and are looking to use it with ubuntu server. The scanner acts as a HID, so we need to hook the keystrokes it generates. We are hoping to use GO to do so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check https://github.com/boombuler/hid (I haven't personally tried it)

Comment: If it is acts as a HID keyboard, then can't you just read the input the same as you would for any other keyboard events coming in over stdin?

Comment: The server won't be logged in, so stdin is not an option. The end goal is to scan a barcodewithout being logged in and send the information over udp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was just to read the raw event and parse it.